the value of useing useRef to component that import with dynamic/next
i'm using next.js
import WysiwygEditor from "../wysiwygEditor";

const CreatePost = () => {
  const editorRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const printRefCurrent = () => {
    console.log(editorRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <WysiwygEditor ref={editorRef} />
      <button onClick={printRefCurrent}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default CreatePost;


import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React, { useImperativeHandle, useRef, forwardRef } from "react";

import "@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css";

const Editor = dynamic(() => import("@toast-ui/react-editor").then((mod) => mod.Editor), { ssr: false });

const WysiwygEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ current: editorRef.current }));

  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        ref={editorRef}
        height="400px"
        initialEditType="wysiwyg"
        previewStyle="vertical"
        hideModeSwitch={true}
        useCommandShortcut={true}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default WysiwygEditor;


above code is my codes that have problem. sorry for the long code.
when i click button, in conosle

currnet property contains a retry function rather than an input value.
can you help me out from this problem.. my english is not good sorry..

To correctly forward the ref to the Editor component and allow the parent component to access its methods, use useImperativeHandle:
  const WysiwygEditor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
 const editorRef = useRef<any>(null);

 // Expose specific methods or properties via ref
 useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getEditor: () => editorRef.current?.getInstance(),
 }));

 return <Editor ref={editorRef} {...props} />;

});
const CreatePost = ({ mainCategory }: PostWriteProps) => {  
...
const submitHandler = {
  onSubmit: (data: any) => {
    const editorInstance = editorRef.current?.getEditor();
    const content = editorInstance?.getMarkdown(); // Or getHTML() based 
                                                    on what you need
  const req = {
    subCategory: currentCategory,
    title: data.title,
    content,
  };
   console.log(req);
   // mutationHandler.mutate(req);
  },

};

...

};
I hope this helps.

is still return retry function in current property.. but thank you so much

import React from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/react-editor';
import '@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css';

interface WysiwygEditorProps {
  editorRef: React.RefObject<Editor>;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line react/function-component-definition
const WysiwygEditor: React.FC<WysiwygEditorProps> = ({ editorRef }) => {
  return (
    <Editor
      ref={editorRef}
      initialValue="초기 내용"
      previewStyle="vertical"
      height="400px"
      initialEditType="markdown"
      useCommandShortcut
    />
  );
};

export default WysiwygEditor;

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/react-editor';

const WysiwygEditor = dynamic(() => import('../components/WysiwygEditor'), { ssr: false });
function ParentComponent() {
  const editorRef = useRef<Editor>(null);

  const handleButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    if (editorRef.current) {
      const editorInstance = editorRef.current.getInstance();
      console.log('editorInstance', editorInstance);
      console.log('Editor content:', editorInstance.getMarkdown());
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <WysiwygEditor editorRef={editorRef} />
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Get Editor Content</button>
    </>
)}

By implementing it this way, you can access the editor normally.!
